# Which stylesheet will be used? (IE conditional statements)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm needing to use a different stylesheet for IE, and I'm wondering about which stylesheet will take control.

For example, I'll use this code in the <head>:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css" />
<!--[if IE]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/ie.css" /><![endif]-->
```

Then will I need to use !important everywhere in the IE stylesheet? Or will the second stylesheet be seen as more important by IE? Does the order matter?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Whichever style has the highest [specificity](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) will win. If you are providing the same selectors in both stylesheets the latest one will win. Otherwise, from the article I linked above:

> 1. Specificity determines, which CSS rule is applied by the browsers.
> 2. Specificity is usually the reason why your CSS-rules don’t apply to some elements, although you think they should.
> 3. Every selector has its place in the specificity hierarchy.
> 4. If two selectors apply to the same element, the one with higher specificity wins.
> 5. There are four distinct categories which define the specificity level of a given selector: inline styles, IDs, classes+attributes and elements.
> 6. You can understand specificity if you love Star Wars: [CSS Specificity Wars](http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html).
> 7. You can understand specificity if you love poker: [CSS Specificity for Poker Players](http://iamacamera.org/default.aspx?id=95)
> 8. When selectors have an equal specificity value, the latest rule is the one that counts.
> 9. When selectors have an unequal specificity value, the more specific rule is the one that counts.
> 10. Rules with more specific selectors have a greater specificity.
> 11. The last rule defined overrides any previous, conflicting rules.
> 12. The embedded style sheet has a greater specificity than other rules.
> 13. ID selectors have a higher specificity than attribute selectors.
> 14. You should always try to use IDs to increase the specificity.
> 15. A class selector beats any number of element selectors.
> 16. The universal selector and inherited selectors have a specificity of 0, 0, 0, 0.
> 17. You can calculate CSS specificity with CSS Specificity Calculator.

[Here are the official docs on it](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity).

Answer (score 1):

The second declaration will override the first in ie.